# Content-Disposition Filename not working on IE

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-headers, content-disposition

I am working on an asp.net/c# web application that allows users to view and download PDF files. When I am clicking on a file, I get to view that in the PDF reader available in the browser, and when I save it, the file should be saved with the name that I have passed via headers. But this is not the behavior in IE7 & IE8

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + f.Name)
```

When I click to save a file, the filename that I am sending over is not being used to save the file, but the filename of the aspx page in the url is being taken. Is this is a bug in IE. Everything works fine when I try it on Google chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + f.name + "\"");` Inline is not working under IE 7-8.

Comment: I think the file name should be enclosed in quotes `Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + f.name+"\"")`